# How to get the metadata of a function from a variable

Tags: clojure, metadata

I have a function which would work on the metadata of a function. I know that I can get the metadata of a function in the following syntax:

```
(meta #'println)
```

It returns with the metadata I am interested in:

```
{:arglists ([& more]), :doc "Same as print followed by (newline)", :added "1.0", :static true, :line 3631, :column 1, :file "clojure/core.clj", :name println, :ns #namespace[clojure.core]}
```

But it is not working if it is inside a variable. I tried the following

```
(defn x [f] (meta #'f))
```

Of course it throws the following error:

```
clojure.lang.Compiler$CompilerException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve var: f in this context, compiling:(/var/folders/zs/_8vy14592dncxyj8mcz4jfyc000_9z/T/boot.user1460390749042099586.clj:1:1)
             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve var: f in this context
```

Not working if I simply use meta:

```
(defn x [f] (meta f))
(x println)
```

Because it returns with a `nil` not with the original meta-data of the `println` function.

Same when I try with backtick:

```
(defn x [f] (meta `f))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case the information you are looking for is contained in the var which contains the function, rather then in the function.

If you are given only the contents of a container you can't read what was written on the box before the object was removed from it.

- namespaces contain `var`s and give them names
- vars have metadata atached to them about the function they contain.
- vars also hold functions.

functions can have metadata, though the specific metadata you are looking for is in hte metadata on the var.

```
(meta #'symbol-here)
```

looks in the current namespace for the var associated with the symbol `symbol-here` and then looks at that object and gets the metadata from it.

if you pass the var itself to the function `f` rather than passing it's contents then you can lookup the metadata from within that function:

```
user> (defn x [f]
        (f "calling f with a string")
        (meta f))
#'user/x
user> (x #'println)
calling f with a string
{:arglists ([& more]), :doc "Same as print followed by (newline)", :added "1.0", :static true, :line 3631, :column 1, :file "clojure/core.clj", :        name println, :ns #namespace[clojure.core]}
```

The important part here is that you passed the object that actually contains the metadata you are looking for (the var) rather then the object that was in the container (the function) it's also worth noting that if you call a var as a function, the var will automatically call the function it contains using the same arguments and pass the response back.

Comment: So, is there a way to get the original metadata I quoted for `println`?

Comment: it depends how your function is called. I'll ad it to the answer

Comment: It is called like I wrote in the question: `(x println)`

Comment: then the answer is sadly, no. it can't be done in a reasonable way. you would have to search every namespace for vars containing the same object you where passed and try to guess the var that contained it.

Comment: Well, that sucks, since my function could also receive anonymous functions and those could not be passed as variables.

Comment: anonymous function's wont have much to say anyway `(meta (fn [] 42))
 --> nil`

Comment: I know, but in those cases I would generate something there.

Comment: @KARASZIIstván Functions (whether anonymous or not) *can* have metadata associated with them, which would then be returned by `meta`.  If you are generating this metadata yourself, you could use `alter-var-root` and `with-meta` to associate meta-data with a function bound to a var, e.g. `println`.

Comment: @NathanDavis I wouldn't alter the `println` var; that just doesn't seem like a good idea. But you could get a new function by adding the metadata from the `println` var to the `println` function, and then pass that to `x`: `(x (with-meta println (meta #'println)))`

Comment: it wouldn't work anyway, functions in clojure.core use direct linking and don't go through the var. They take a fasttrack starting in clojure 1.8 (or was it 1.9?)

Comment: @ArthurUlfeldt Yeah, [direct linking was added in Clojure 1.8.](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/changes.md#11-direct-linking) Running `(let [m (meta #'println)] (alter-var-root #'println #(with-meta % m)) (meta println))` from a Clojure 1.8 REPL seems to work, though...